# format-number() rounding inconsistency

Tags: saxon

I'm noticing some inconsistency in rounding with `format-number()`:

```
format-number(37.5,'#') ( 38 : String )
format-number(38.5,'#') ( 38 : String )
```

To expand on this:

```
(1 to 10) ! (. + 0.5) ! format-number(.,'#')
(1 to 10) ! (. + 0.5) ! round(.)
(1 to 10) ! (. + 0.5) ! round-half-to-even(.)
```

Results in

```
("2","2","4","4","6","6","8","8","10","10")
(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
(2,2,4,4,6,6,8,8,10,10)
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?  I'm using Saxon-PE 11.4

Comment: https://rounding.to/understanding-the-bankers-rounding/  I can't say with absolute certainty this is the rounding algorithm in use here, but the main point is that there are many ways to "round" and the behavior you are describing is one of them. All of which comes as a surprise since many of use were taught one method and never told there were others (e.g., see also https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/rounding-methods.html)

Comment: Interesting.  I've confirmed round-half-to-even() behaves the same way.  Is this the default behavior of format-number() rounding, instead of round()?

Comment: `format-number(37.5,'#'), format-number(38.5,'#')` in BaseX 10 also gives 38 two times so it is (probably) not a Saxon bug. The glory details must be somewhere in https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-format-number

Comment: The next question will be can `format-number()` be configured to use `round()` instead of `round-half-to-even()`

Comment: You can't configure the rounding behaviour of format-number() but you can of course `round()` the number before formatting.

Comment: That would work only if I know the pattern would be '#' or '0' or similar.  If the pattern is variable, the we'd have to check the pattern to know how to round.  E.g. if it were `format-number(38.65,'#.#')`, then I could not simply `round()`, as that would not generate 38.7.  I would need to `round(.,1)` if the pattern were '#.#' or '0.0', and `round(.,2)` if the pattern were '#.##' or '0.00', etc.  Basically I'd have to understand and parse all possible patterns to do this effectively.  Correct?

Answer (score 1):

@topsail, your hint found the answer.  XSLT spec 4.7.5 bullet 6 https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#formatting-the-number says:

> The rounded number is defined to be the result of converting the mantissa to an xs:decimal value, as described above, and then calling the function fn:round-half-to-even